# Why adding bracket in If statements with Multiple AND OR gives different result?

Tags: c++, if-statement, logical-operators

I have simple program that has 1 AND and multiple OR operators as below :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool a = true;
    bool b = true;
    bool c = true;
    bool d = true;

    if (!a && b || c || d)
        cout << "run";
    else
        cout << "pass";

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the program will output `pass` because I declare a as true. But, if you run the program it will give output : `run`

If I change the if statement line by adding bracket to

```
if (!a && (b || c || d))
        cout << "run";
    else
        cout << "pass";
```

It will give the expected output `pass`. Why does it work that way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because the logical and operator (`&&`) has a higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the logical or operator (`||`), and the logical negation operator (`!`) has the highest precedence of the three.

This means that the expression `!a && b || c || d` is grouped as `((((!a) && b) || c) || d)`.  Working from the inside out:

- `!a` is `false` -> `(((false && b) || c) || d)`
- `false && b` is `false` -> `((false || c) || d)`
- `false || c` is `true` -> `(true || d)`
- `true || d` is `true` -> `true`

So the whole expression evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Duh, It's been a while and forgot to check precedence table. I recalled both of && and || has same precedence. Thanks for detail explanation

Comment: @gameon67 Even if they had the same precedence, it would still be evaluated left-to-right, so your results would stay the same.

Comment: yes, I made terrible assumption, I thought if the first AND operation gives false, then it will break the if statement right away.

Answer (score 4):

The `&&` operator has greater *precedence* than `||` in C++ (as well as the majority of other programming languages).  So, your first version of the code was actually executing as if you had written this:

```
if ((!a && b) || c || d)  // if (false || true || true)
    cout << "run";
else
    cout << "pass";
```

Of course, the `if` statement passes as true, because both `c` and `d` were set to `true` at the start.

Answer (score 4):

Operator precedence, which as you can see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence
means && will be evaluated before ||.

Answer (score 3):

Tim and Miles have the right answer, and you should accept one of them.

I wanted to explain a programming concept here as well, that is important if you plan to ever code for work.

It's really important to understand the operator precedence thing, but you probably don't want to have to try to pencil check all your code when it misbehaves.  For this reason, it's helpful to be very explicit in how you write code.  I would, instead of what you have written, do something like this:

```
bool should_run(bool a, bool b, bool c, bool d) {
  if( ! a ) {
    return true;
  }
  return b || c || d;
}

if( should_run(a, b, c, d)) {
  cout << "run";
} else {
  cout << "pass";
}
```

Longer to write? Yes. Longer to read? Maybe. Longer to understand what you're doing? No, definitely not.  Especially 2 months from now when you're trying to debug a thorny condition, and don't remember why you have that big long logic string.

Even better with comments:

```
// returns true if the conditions are right to run,
// otherwise, return false to indicate a pass.
bool should_run(bool a, bool b, bool c, bool d) {
  // if coach said we don't run, then we pass!
  if( ! a ) {
    return true;
  } // coach said pass.

  // if the tight end, halfback, or running back are ready, then run.
  // if all three are not ready, then I guess we're passing.
  return b || c || d;
}

if( should_run(a, b, c, d)) {
  cout << "run";
} else {
  cout << "pass";
}
```

To those who will complain about execution efficiency: Compilers can take care of optimizing this for the most part through inlining.  If not, I say "First make it work, later, when you discover a problem, make it work faster".  After all, 
"[Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least of most of it) in programming](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_(1974))".

Comment: Somehow looks overkill for this simple logic, but actually it is a very important tip and very useful for beginner in order to become a professional programmer

Comment: Agree @gameon67 -- but if you're in the habit of overkill, the strenuous logic becomes simple.

Answer (score 0):

Operations have precedence and operations having same precedence value will executed serially from left to right.